# jquery set text

Tags: jquery, text

I have some div

```
<div id="editCatalogListItemHideMe">
    <div class="listItem">
        <table class="sectionTable">
            <tr>
                <td class="sectionLeft">
                    <span id="numberLabel"></span><span>:</span>
                </td>
                <td class="sectionCenter">
                    <span id="contentLabel"></span>
                </td>
                <td class="sectionRight">
                    <img runat="server" src="images/noselected.png" class="selectImage" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

and i want to set text to numberLabel and contentLabel

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var counter = 1;

        var content = ["val1", "val2", "val3", "val4", "val5"];

        $('#AddSectionButton').click(function () {
            var section = $('#editCatalogListItemHideMe').html();
            $(section).find('#numberLabel').text(counter);
            $(section).find('#contentLabel').text(content[counter % content.length]);

            $('div#editCatalogLeftBottomContent').append(section);

            counter++;

    });
```

This script appends empty div, without my values. How can i make this?

Comment: you've got alot of crazy/messy javascript; section is totally wrong.. delete the .html() at the end.. and change counter%content.length to content.length%counter.. and remove the whole line that says append.. ahyeah, and remove the 'text' after .text(

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2011/01/modifying-html-strings-using-jquery.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
var $section = $($('#editCatalogListItemHideMe').html());
$section.find('#numberLabel').text(counter);
$section.find('#contentLabel').text('text', content[counter % content.length]);
$('div#editCatalogLeftBottomContent').append($section);
```

In your current code, you're defining `section` as a string. Then, at the lines following the `section` declaration, you're wrapping the value in a JQuery object. This will modify the contents of the newly created object, but **not** the `section` variable.

I've adjusted your code, so that `$section` is a variable which refers to a newly created JQuery object. The lines after the declaration operate on the newly created object. At the end of the code, the HTML is appended.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you write `$(section)`, you're creating a detached DOM tree, manipulating it, **and then discarding it**.

You need to reuse and then append it.

Answer (score 1):

the line:

```
var section = $('#editCatalogListItemHideMe').html();
```

might be the evil-thing :)
try changing it to :

```
var section = $('#editCatalogListItemHideMe');
```

Answer (score 1):

`id`'s must be unique on a page, you are effectively cloning an existing element, and re-using the same `id`'s. Change `numberLabel` and `contentLabel` in classes, and use `.numberLabel` and `'.contentLabel` inside your `find`'s.

Also you're discarding your reference to `$(section)` - so create once and re-use

```
var section = $($('#editCatalogListItemHideMe').html());
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/MwvJA/